# sql query COUNT number of occurences when joining a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to return the names of all members that have registered a tasting of a coffe in my DB, and count number of tasting each name has left.

```
select bruker.navn, COUNT(*) from kaffesmaking inner join bruker on kaffesmaking.bruker_epost = bruker.epost
```

table "user" has the columns

name, email , password

table "tasting (alias kaffesmaking) has the columns:

id, note, date, score, user_email, coffename

I want a list displaying

names with numbers of tastings done by that particular user.

i.e

John Johnson 5
Jessie ashford 3
Paul newman 8

Where the number represents the number of rows that specific user has added in the tasting table.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you need to add a "group by" to your SQL

```
SELECT bruker.navn
     , COUNT(*) as tastings
  FROM kaffesmaking
  INNER JOIN bruker
       ON kaffesmaking.bruker_epost = bruker.epost;
  group by bruker.navn;
```

Comment: oh god - im tired. Thanks alot mate!!